# Meaning of "If I were any better I would be twins"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I noted a phrase recently which was:

> If I were any better I'd be twins.

There was another version of it too which was:

> If I were any better I'd be dangerous.

Does the speaker mean that if they would have been any better they would be twins or dangerous but still they are not? So it seems more of a wish to me?

Comment: ''If I were any better I'd be twins''.  Wow I have never heard that before in my life, that's truly bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are NOT two versions of the same thing.

The first emphasises that the person couldn't possibly be an better (at a particular thing)

The second is much more metaphorical. It can be used in so many situations, but I'm struggling to come up with a good example.

Comment: The phrase gets used in [this blog](https://www.awakeningseedschool.org/2012/06/one-of-a-kind/), if you want to start with that.

Comment: https://www.waywordradio.org/if-i-were-any-better-id/